# Datepicker how to exclude days in a week?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to prohibit the choice of days off (sа, su)?

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
 firstDay: 1,
  minDate: 5,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Are the days off always weekends? Or can they be other dates? Regardless, the duplicate link above answers both.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is what need